# Split a text tab separated file and add to array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following text file, which contains tab separated values. I want to split these values and add same to an array in Javascript. How can I do this by omitting the header?

```
Id  Symbol
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
6   F
7   G
```

I have tried this so far:

```
var data;
$.get('../interactors.txt', function(d){
    data = d.split('/\r?\n/');
    //console.log(data);
    var lines = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        lines.push(data[i].split('/[ ]+/)'));
    }
    console.log(lines);
});
```

Comment: Please show us the code that you have done yet, It will help us to help you more easily

Comment: @Ibnelaiq I have added the code

Comment: Okay give me some time

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to change is skipping the header, you can simply start from `i = 1`:

```
var data;
$.get('../interactors.txt', function(d){
    data = d.split('/\r?\n/');
    //console.log(data);
    var lines = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
        lines.push(data[i].split('/[ ]+/)'));
    }
    console.log(lines);
});
```